# How to exit and close FX Text Editor (the text editor of FX File Explorer) - end of question

Tags: applications

Thanks for your answers - here my final report:

1.

The "FX file explorer" is in one of the windows and cannot be removed.

I intended to kill the process by its PID. To get the PID I used the App "Activity Monitor" (other task manager for Andoid I have forgotten). But this App had not discovered and not listed "FX file explorer".

I made a test: In another terminal I have run "FX file explorer" and have it work in Google Drive in order to not be idle. Also for this test was true: "Activity Monitor" App had not discovered and not listed "FX file explorer".

2.

Regarding if FX is good or not: In some articles of Journals in Internet, FX was commented as the best Filemanager in Android. Many days I have dealt with a task, but I was forced to give up.

Regards

Comment: We appreciate your input, however I'm afraid you mis-posted this as a question instead of an answer on your own question. Being a Q&A site, questions are only for asking questions, but you can post an answer on your own question by filling the Answer box below :)